# Can't compile ORMLite statement

Tags: java, android, select, ormlite

I'm trying to compile ORMLite query statement but I'm getting the following `SQLException`:

```
Could not compile this SELECT_LONG statement since the caller is expecting a SELECT statement.  Check your QueryBuilder methods.
```

I've tried all the possible ways to do so but I'm always getting it, my primary try was:

```
QueryBuilder<Message, Integer> messagesQueryBuilder = dbManager.getMessagesDao().queryBuilder();   
Where<Message, Integer> resultedQuery = messagesQueryBuilder.where().in(Message.SCHOOL_COLUMN_NAME, schoolIntegerQueryBuilder);
Long count = messagesQueryBuilder.countOf();
messagesQueryBuilder.orderBy(Message.MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP, false);
messagesQueryBuilder.queryForFirst(); // getting it here
```

And then I tried to prepare the query first:

```
messagesQueryBuilder.orderBy(Message.MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP, false);
Message message = dbManager.getMessagesDao().query(messagesQueryBuilder.prepare()).get(0); // getting here also
```

And finally tried to prepare it separately in a new object then using that object:

```
PreparedQuery<Message> queryForMessage = messagesQueryBuilder.orderBy(Message.MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP, false).prepare();
Message message = dbManager.getMessagesDao().query(queryForMessage).get(0); // also failing here with the same Exception
```

I don't know what I'm exactly doing wrong but even though I tried all the possible ways that normally working with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found where is the problem, in ORMLite when executing a method you are like executing a statements not only getting values to store it somewhere else, so when executing this:

```
Long count = messagesQueryBuilder.countOf();
```

now the `messagesQueryBuilder` contains only the retrieved count not the whole query result that was stored in it before.

Hence, to solve my problem, I reordered the code execution lines to be as the following:

```
QueryBuilder<Message, Integer> messagesQueryBuilder = dbManager.getMessagesDao().queryBuilder();   
Where<Message, Integer> resultedQuery = messagesQueryBuilder.where().in(Message.SCHOOL_COLUMN_NAME, schoolIntegerQueryBuilder);

messagesQueryBuilder.orderBy(Message.MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP, false);
Message message = messagesQueryBuilder.queryForFirst();

Long count = messagesQueryBuilder.countOf();
```

Comment: That's exactly right @Muhammed.  The `countOf()` sets some flags on the query in terms of the type of results.